# How to optimize sql multiple select queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I have a query that calculates wait time for each record from the `Transactions` table and calculates SUM and MAX wait time for each of the group below based on `receivedDate` and `claimedDt`.
Here is a basic query:

```
SELECT
    '2022-06-01' as reportDate,
    waitTimeSubQuery.currentAssignedQueueId,
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueAccessPointId,
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueName AS QueueName,
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueReportCategory,
    waitTimeSubQuery.queuePriority,
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueOrganizationHierarchyId,
    COUNT(waitTimeSubQuery.id) AS totalCasesWaiting,
    SUM(CASE WHEN waitTimeSubQuery.waitTimeMinutes > 0 THEN waitTimeSubQuery.waitTimeMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS sumWaitTimeMinutes,
    MAX(CASE WHEN waitTimeSubQuery.waitTimeMinutes > 0 THEN waitTimeSubQuery.waitTimeMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS maxWaitTimeMinutes
FROM (SELECT
    id,
    currentAssignedQueueId,
    queueAccessPointId,
    queueName,
    queueReportCategory,
    queuePriority,
    queueOrganizationHierarchyId,
(CASE WHEN (receivedDateUTC > '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z' OR receivedDate > '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z') AND (appointmentDT IS NULL OR appointmentDT < '2022-09-28T12:58:47')

THEN CAST(DateDiff(MINUTE,
    CASE WHEN receivedDateUTC > '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z'
    THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(receivedDateUTC AS VARCHAR), 0, 19), 'Z')
    ELSE TRY_CAST(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(receivedDate AS VARCHAR), 0, 10), SUBSTRING(CAST(createdDT AS VARCHAR), 10, 9)), 'Z') AS DATETIME2) END,
    CASE WHEN claimedDT > '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z' AND claimedDT < '2022-06-01T23:59:00Z' AND transactionStatus != 'WaitingAssignment'
    THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(claimedDT AS VARCHAR), 0, 19), 'Z')
    ELSE '2022-06-01T23:59:00Z' END
) AS BIGINT)
ELSE 0 END) AS waitTimeMinutes
FROM @transactionsList
WHERE receivedDate <= '2022-06-01T00:00:00'
AND (claimedDT >= '2022-06-02T00:00:00' OR transactionStatus = 'WaitingAssignment')) waitTimeSubQuery
GROUP BY waitTimeSubQuery.currentAssignedQueueId, 
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueAccessPointId, 
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueName, 
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueReportCategory, 
    waitTimeSubQuery.queuePriority, 
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueOrganizationHierarchyId
```

I want to calculate **statistics** for each day for the period of 30 days and the only difference is dates used for calculating `waitTimeMinutes` (based on `endDate`, `claimedDt`, `receivedDate`) and filtering by `receivedDate` and `claimedDt`.

I tried to save sub-set of the Transactions data into a table variable and reuse it in multiple select queries to get the statistics for each day, but this script runs too slow

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @transactionsList TABLE (
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
    currentAssignedQueueId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
    queueAccessPointId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
    queueName VARCHAR(100), 
    queueReportCategory VARCHAR(100), 
    queuePriority INT, 
    queueOrganizationHierarchyId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    receivedDate DATE,
    claimedDT DATE,
    transactionStatus VARCHAR(100),
    receivedDateUTC DATE,
    appointmentDT DATE,
    createdDT DATE)


INSERT INTO @transactionsList
SELECT
    Transactions.id,
    Transactions.currentAssignedQueueId, 
    Queues.accessPointId as queueAccessPointId,
    Queues.name as queueName,
    Queues.reportCategory as queueReportCategory,
    Queues.priority as queuePriority,
    Queues.organizationHierarchyId as queueOrganizationHierarchyId,
    Transactions.receivedDate,
    Transactions.claimedDT,
    Transactions.transactionStatus,
    Transactions.receivedDateUTC,
    Transactions.appointmentDT,
    Transactions.createdDT
FROM Transactions 
LEFT JOIN Queues ON Transactions.currentAssignedQueueId = Queues.Id
WHERE Transactions.consumerId = '66458f4a-b3d4-4f80-93d4-5aa3ea123249'
    AND Transactions.isActive = 1
    AND Transactions.receivedDate <= '2022-06-30T00:00:00'
    AND (Transactions.claimedDT >= '2022-06-02T00:00:00' OR Transactions.transactionStatus = 'WaitingAssignment')


--SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @transactionsList

-- 2022-06-01
SELECT
    '2022-06-01' as reportDate,
    waitTimeSubQuery.currentAssignedQueueId,
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueAccessPointId,
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueName AS QueueName,
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueReportCategory,
    waitTimeSubQuery.queuePriority,
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueOrganizationHierarchyId,
    COUNT(waitTimeSubQuery.id) AS totalCasesWaiting,
    SUM(CASE WHEN waitTimeSubQuery.waitTimeMinutes > 0 THEN waitTimeSubQuery.waitTimeMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS sumWaitTimeMinutes,
    MAX(CASE WHEN waitTimeSubQuery.waitTimeMinutes > 0 THEN waitTimeSubQuery.waitTimeMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS maxWaitTimeMinutes
FROM (SELECT
    id,
    currentAssignedQueueId,
    queueAccessPointId,
    queueName,
    queueReportCategory,
    queuePriority,
    queueOrganizationHierarchyId,
(CASE WHEN (receivedDateUTC > '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z' OR receivedDate > '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z') AND (appointmentDT IS NULL OR appointmentDT < '2022-09-28T12:58:47')

THEN CAST(DateDiff(MINUTE,
    CASE WHEN receivedDateUTC > '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z'
    THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(receivedDateUTC AS VARCHAR), 0, 19), 'Z')
    ELSE TRY_CAST(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(receivedDate AS VARCHAR), 0, 10), SUBSTRING(CAST(createdDT AS VARCHAR), 10, 9)), 'Z') AS DATETIME2) END,
    CASE WHEN claimedDT > '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z' AND claimedDT < '2022-06-01T23:59:00Z' AND transactionStatus != 'WaitingAssignment'
    THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(claimedDT AS VARCHAR), 0, 19), 'Z')
    ELSE '2022-06-01T23:59:00Z' END
) AS BIGINT)
ELSE 0 END) AS waitTimeMinutes
FROM @transactionsList
WHERE receivedDate <= '2022-06-01T00:00:00'
AND (claimedDT >= '2022-06-02T00:00:00' OR transactionStatus = 'WaitingAssignment')) waitTimeSubQuery
GROUP BY waitTimeSubQuery.currentAssignedQueueId, 
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueAccessPointId, 
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueName, 
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueReportCategory, 
    waitTimeSubQuery.queuePriority, 
    waitTimeSubQuery.queueOrganizationHierarchyId
```

And the part from '2022-06-01' repeats 30 times for each day from the range respectively.

Is there any possibility to optimize this script? For my data it runs nearly **49 seconds** and the number of the records in the table is only 7kk and it's far way more on other environment.

**---EDIT---**

Here are the definitions for the tables `Transactions` and `Queues`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions] (
    [id]                            UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [accessPointId]                 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [isNonLobby]                    BIT                NULL,
    [printReceipt]                  BIT                NULL,
    [isExpressed]                   BIT                NULL,
    [isAssignedBySupervisor]        BIT                NULL,
    [dateAssignedBySupervisor]      VARCHAR (30)       NULL,
    [dateAssignedBySupervisorLocal] DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NULL,
    [supervisorOverrideId]          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [supervisorId]                  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [isNewHousehold]                BIT                NULL,
    [householdId]                   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [receivedDate]                  DATE               NULL,
    [receivedDateUTC]               DATETIME2 (7)      NULL,
    [transactionStatus]             VARCHAR (20)       NULL,
    [claimedDT]                     DATETIME2 (7)      NULL,
    [claimedDTLocal]                DATE               NULL,
    [initiallyClaimedById]          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [completedDT]                   DATETIME2 (7)      NULL,
    [appointmentDT]                 DATETIME2 (7)      NULL,
    [completedDTLocal]              DATE               NULL,
    [completedById]                 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [remarks]                       VARCHAR (MAX)      NULL,
    [currentAssignedQueueId]        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [currentAssignedUserId]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [preTriageTransactionId]        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [isAddClaim]                    BIT                NULL,
    [receiptId]                     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [ticketNumber]                  VARCHAR (100)      NULL,
    [deliNumber]                    VARCHAR (100)      NULL,
    [tasksCount]                    BIGINT             NULL,
    [projectedWaitTime]             BIGINT             NULL,
    [actualWaitTimeMinutes]         BIGINT             NULL,
    [assignWaitTime]                BIGINT             NULL,
    [transactionTimeMinutes]        BIGINT             NULL,
    [triageTimeMinutes]             BIGINT             NULL,
    [outcomeId]                     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [outcomeReasonId]               UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [outcomeType]                   VARCHAR (50)       NULL,
    [dueDate]                       VARCHAR (30)       NULL,
    [dueDateLocal]                  DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NULL,
    [isDueDateToday]                VARCHAR (30)       NULL,
    [isUnknownHousehold]            BIT                NULL,
    [activityId]                    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [programId]                     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [reviewMonthDueDate]            VARCHAR (40)       NULL,
    [reviewMonthDueDateLocal]       DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NULL,
    [officeId]                      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [isOnceManuallyPaused]          BIT                NULL,
    [pkey]                          VARCHAR (100)      NULL,
    [isActive]                      BIT                NULL,
    [consumerId]                    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [organizationName]              VARCHAR (50)       NULL,
    [modifiedBy]                    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [modifiedDT]                    DATETIME2 (7)      NULL,
    [modifiedDTLocal]               DATE               NULL,
    [createdBy]                     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [createdDT]                     DATETIME2 (7)      NULL,
    [createdDTLocal]                DATE               NULL,
    [_ts]                           BIGINT             NULL,
    [type]                          VARCHAR (50)       NULL,
    [timezoneId]                    VARCHAR (50)       NULL
);



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Queues] (
    [id]                                 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [name]                               VARCHAR (255)    NULL,
    [accessPointId]                      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [organizationHierarchyId]            UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [assignedOrganizationHierarchyLevel] VARCHAR (20)     NULL,
    [bundlingGroup]                      BIGINT           NULL,
    [reportCategory]                     VARCHAR (100)    NULL,
    [priority]                           INT              NULL,
    [businessProcessThreshold]           BIGINT           NULL,
    [calculateProjectedWaitTime]         BIT              NULL,
    [waitTimeUnits]                      VARCHAR (10)     NULL,
    [hasCarryOver]                       BIT              NULL,
    [defaultTransactionTimeMinutes]      BIGINT           NULL,
    [latestQueueMetricId]                UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [isAppointment]                      BIT              NULL,
    [consumerId]                         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [organizationName]                   VARCHAR (50)     NULL,
    [modifiedBy]                         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [modifiedDT]                         DATE             NULL,
    [createdBy]                          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [createdDT]                          DATE             NULL,
    [_ts]                                BIGINT           NULL
);
```

And an index for the `Transactions` table (this is the only one index for this table and there are no indexes for the `Queues` table):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nci_wi_Transactions_EBAFDE3A7C2969265E76135FBA69188D] ON [dbo].[Transactions]
(
    [consumerId] ASC,
    [isActive] ASC,
    [receivedDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE([appointmentDT],[claimedDT],[createdDT],[currentAssignedQueueId],[id],[receivedDateUTC],[transactionStatus]) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Here is the link on GitHub for the execution plan and the full query
https://github.com/sskotliar/query_optimization

[**PasteThePlan link**](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=By4REBNGo)

Comment: For query performance help, we need tables and indexes, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create. To offer useful advice about your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions,  and your actual (not estimated) query plan. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: @Charlieface pastetheplan.com - this website isn't loading for me even with a VPN, I pushed execution plan and the full query to GitHub repo

Comment: @O.Jones thanks! I added the link for the execution plan and the full query, please let me know If I missed something

Comment: You have the same query multiple times for unclear reasons, and PasteThePlan has a maximum size of 2MB XML

Comment: Well I need to calculate statistics for each of the day in a selected period. For example, I need to calculate statistics for the period from 2022-06-01 to 2022-06-30, there may be transactions that repeats for multiple days and their wait time need to be recalculated for each day. 
You are right, they are actually the same, but the difference is in the dates used for the calculations of wait times and detecting waiting cases and I really can't figure out how to write this in a different manner.

Comment: The query on PastThePlan link calculates statistics for 2022-06-01, and I need it for the whole period from the 2022-06-01 to 2022-06-30 and that's why I duplicate queries

Comment: Sounds like you need to start with a calendar table and join everything else `FROM Dates d LEFT JOIN EvereythingElseHere ON receivedDate >= d.StartOfDate AND receivedDate < d.StartOfNextDate`

Comment: Looking at your plan: It seems you need some indexes: a clustered PK on `Queues.Id`, and a filtered index `Transactions (currentAssignedQueueId, receivedDate) INCLUDE (OtherColumnsHere) WHERE (consumerId = '66458f4a-b3d4-4f80-93d4-5aa3ea123249' AND Transactions.isActive = 1)` and a clustered index `@transactionsList
 (currentAssignedQueueId, queueAccessPointId, queueName, queueReportCategory, queuePriority, queueOrganizationHierarchyId)`. Your current indexes are doing absolutely nothing for this query. The use of the table variable is unnecessary, if you use my suggestion of a calendar table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option - 1

You can improve the performance of your query by using a `CTE`. How does `CTE` work? The query you write inside the `WITH` command is executed only once, and its result is stored as a temporary table. This allows you to execute your large query with multiple join in it once. In the remaining cases, only its result is used. But as I understood you call your query with different filters. If this is true, so please see Option 2.

Option - 2

If the result of your repeatable query is large, and you call this query with different filters, it is recommended that you, insert result of repeatable query into temp table, then create needed indexes for this temp table. Then you can use that table as much as you need. Since your table has indexes so your filters will be works high performance.

For each of the options mentioned above, it is recommended that you view Query Plan. Because the query plan may change from the DB side depending on the count of records in the tables.